# Python Warning message display

Tags: python-2.7, openerp-7

I have written a function like below Written in Python and XML. Which function like if user selects past date it will display a warning message called 'Past date not allowed.' I need to get warning message like 'Past date not allowed. Date selected is 04-09-2015(It should display the selected date also). How can we do this.

Python:

```
 def onchange_start_date_past(self, cr, uid, ids, start_date, eofdate, year2, context=None):
            res = {'value':{}}

            chng_year = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            today = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            current_date = datetime.strptime(today, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            if chng_year.year and year2:
                if str(chng_year.year) != str(year2):
                    #res['value']['date_start'] = ''
                    res.update({'warning': {'title': _('Warning !'), 'message': _('Please enter correct Year.')}})
                    return res
                d = self.months_between1(chng_year, current_date) 
                if d < 0:
                    #res['value']['date_start'] = ''
                    res.update({'warning': {'title': _('Warning !'), 'message': _('Past date not allowed.')}})
                    return res
                return start_date
            else:
                return False
```

XML:

```
<field name='date_start' on_change="onchange_start_date_past(date_start, date_end, parent.year)"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: res.update({'warning': {'title': _('Warning !'), 'message': _('Past date not allowed.' + str(start_date))}})